# highlight the syntax of `MySQL` queries

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-highlighting

I've been looking for a way to provide syntax highlighting for MySQL queries in `phpMyAdmin`, but I couldn't find how.

I have phpMyAdmin installed on Linux Mint 14

Isn't there a way to highlight the syntax of `MySQL` queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your setting for CodeMirror is off, which does the Syntax Highlighting. 
Its under Settings => SQL Queries => [x] Enable Code Mirror

Here's a pic http://grab.by/d5Gu

Also I think CodeMirror has been added to phpMyAdmin in Version 3.5, so if you have an older version, you probably will need to upgrade.